# Vertical asymptote (or any?) at removable discontinuity

Tags: functions

If I have a removable discontinuity, do i have any kind of asymptote?

I originally thought no, but this confused me a bit:

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/asymtote4.htm

Close to the bottom, it says that the function (with a removable discontinuity) has both a vertical asymptote at x = 2 and a slant asymptote. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but a graph can have a vertical asymptote as well as a slant asymptote. There is nothing wrong with that...

Comment: That's not what I am asking. Can a graph have BOTH a vertical asymptote at x = 2 AND a removable discontinuity at x = 2? I've been told no by my teacher, so that's what I am not understanding.

Comment: A function $f$ is said to have a vertical asymptote at $a$ if, and only if, $\lim \limits_{x\to a}(f(x))=\pm \infty$ and it is said to have a removable discontinuity at $a$ if, and only if, $\lim \limits_{x\to a}(f(x))\in \mathbb R$, so your teacher is right by virtue of the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given is incorrect, there is no vertical asymptote for that example.  It has a removable discontinuity at $x=2$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so as well.

Comment: THe problem lies with purple math. It first suggest that there is a vertical asymptote and then it says that it actually is a removable disc. I can now see where the confusion comes from. The graph has no vertical asymptote at all. So I concure with Paul (+1)